# Is there a way to edit a javascript in browser while debugging

Tags: javascript, extjs

I use `ext.js` heavily in my application for the all UI development. Now I want
 to know if there is a way I can edit the javascript while debugging in the browser itself which will help avoid deployment and fasten my development process.

Comment: If you are using Chrome click F12 and navigate to Source and there you can add breakpoint and change your code.I personally like Chrome for Debugging Javascript.

Answer (score 1):

You can

1. download `firebug(best for mozilla, i prefer this)`.
2. in case of `Safari` you need `web inspector`.
3. firebug `lite`(others)
4. firefox default editor `(ctrl+shift+k)`.
5. chrome default editor(f12)

Comment: **Have** to? What about `Ctrl + Shift + K` in _FireFox_? Or about Developer Tools feature of _Chrome_? _IE_ even comes with a debugger these days.